# Failed to export from shapefile to CSV in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fields-attributes, export, csv

I have a shapefile that I want to export the attributes to CSV.  However, I get the following message.  I have not done anything to the shapefile following the creation of the layer.

> Export to vector file failed. Error: Creation of field Assoc_phas
> failed (OGR error: Attempt to create field Assoc_phas, but a field
> with this name already exists.)

Any idea why it is not exporting?

Answer (score 8):

The error message is quite explicit and clear:

> a field with this name already exists.

It seems you have two fields with the same name (maybe truncated by the fieldname length constraint in Shapefiles, [limited to 10 characters](http://switchfromshapefile.org/#10characters)). Check your fields and rename one, or exclude it from export.

In the export dialog window, you have the option to include/exclude fields or to rename them:

*Check the box (red rectangle) to include/exclude a field; change `Export_name` (highlighted in yellow) to save the field under another name:*

[image]